# Highlight matching strings, found in in a form-field text box, either from a table or static array (using MS Access)

Tags: vba, string, function, ms-access, instr

I have an Access tool/database with external database (ODBC) connections. It's purpose is to review call logs for issues and the user will decide the severity based on the contents of a message.

I have an idea, to assist the review, using VBA.  I created an with about 50 strings, and compare that to a field (memo format) in a form (bound to a table column).  I want the routine to ONLY highlight the matching portion of the string.

An example is:

If the array string contains "Repor", it will change the font size and color of only those letters within the memo field Like **Repor**ted, .  with be larger font and different color

I can successfully do this in Excel VBA with this section of code below ("findar" is a pre-built array, rng1 is the designated range)

```
For i = LBound(findar) To UBound(findar)
    For Each rngcell In rng1
    startPos = 0
    startPos = InStr(rngcell, findar(i))
            If InStr(rngcell, findar(i)) <> 0 Then
               rngcell.Characters(startPos, Len(findar(i))).Font.Color = vbBlue
               rngcell.Characters(startPos, Len(findar(i))).Font.Size = 18
            End If
    Next rngcell
    Next I
```

"Character", apparently doesn't exist in Access, so I'm trying this,  triggered in the "Got Focus" event:  It fails with RunTime error 13.  I'm certain this is doable, but apparently not by me.....

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim startpos As Long
'findar is an array
'incident text is inside the form field

  findar = Array("returned", "failed") 'real array is about 50 strings
  inctext = Me.txtincidentdesc
  lngred = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  lngblack = RGB(0, 0, 0)

'reset to default
  Me.txtincidentdesc.FontBold = False
  Me.txtincidentdesc.ForeColor = lngblack
  Me.txtincidentdesc.FontSize = 10

startpos = 0

For i = LBound(findar) To UBound(findar)
  With Me.txtincidentdesc
   If InStr(inctext, findar(i)) <> 0 Then
     SelStart = InStr(inctext, findar(i))
     SelLength = Len(findar(i))
       txtincidentdesc(Mid(inctext, SelStart, SelLength)).ForeColor = lngred   'fails here RunTime error 13

      '  Me.txtincidentdesc.ForeColor = lngred ' this works fine
      '  Me.txtincidentdesc.FontSize = 20      'this works fine
End If

End With
Next
End Sub
```

I've also considered using a recordset and compare that against the memo field but that also failed.  Thanks for any input or help on this.  Maybe I'm just approaching it wrong

Mark

Comment: You can't format part of the text in access, that I am aware of, doesn't work quite like excel.

Comment: Warcupine:  I was also looking at maybe using a constant, then using HTML "<font color=""""red"""">" and a find/replace routine. Seems doable, but was hoping to be able to adapt what I already know (because it's often faster).

Comment: What is exact message of error 13 and which line triggers? Field and/or textbox must be set as RichText to display HTML formatting.

Comment: Hansup and June7,  Nope it's short text datatype.  I've changed it to rich text (thanks!), and put the VBA method on the back burner, and am working on a find/replace routine with HTML formatting.  Tedious.....and SLOW at best, but I found an old Allen Browne method that I may be able to adapt. @http://allenbrowne.com/AppSearchHighlight.html.  Not sure how much overhead this will be with two passess, and 200 searches per response, against 40-80 words (on average) in each response.  Worth a shot I guess.  I'll post any updates or questions as I sort this out.